# Instantiate a Record in a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, reflection, record

I am using a `Record` as a DTO:

```
public record AccountTypeDTO(string Id, string Name):IEntityDTOBase;
```

`IEntityDTOBase` is used only to access both properties `Id` and `Name`.

At this step I'm creating an instance in a generic method like that with reflection:

```
    internal async IAsyncEnumerable<TEntityDTO> GetAsyncDTO<TEntityDTO>() where TEntityDTO:class,IEntityDTOBase 
    {
        yield return (TEntityDTO)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TEntityDTO),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),"thirdItem" ) ;           
    }
```

It works but I don't like.

Now I'm trying to follow this track:

```
    internal async IAsyncEnumerable<TEntityDTO> GetAsyncDTO<TEntityDTO>() where TEntityDTO:class,IEntityDTOBase,new()
    {
        yield return new TEntityDTO() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "thirdItem" };
        
    }
```

1. `new()` is mandatory to be able to create the instance in the generic method.
2. As I have the `new()` constraint, the caller of the method complaining `must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor, blà, blà, blà`
3. He also complains about `Id` and `Name` in the construction about readonly property

I can implement setters on `AccountTypeDTO` and parameterless constructor to probably solve the issue but I'll loose the immuability and the benefit of a record, not an option.

Is there any other option to avoid reflection?